# Running Jenkins on Remote windows machine

Tags: windows, jenkins, remote-desktop

I am working on a remote Windows system and have the requirement of running Jenkins in it. Although I'm able to install it in that system, I couldn't run it as it isn't able to run on localhost. I tried adding IP address in hosts file as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765443/accessing-localhost-from-virtual-machine) but it didn't work as well. Also tried looking in to Jenkins.xml file if I can change some configuration into it but no luck with that as well.

How can I run Jenkins in my remote Windows machine?

Comment: when you talk about remote windows system are you talking about a remote virtual machine or remote virtual desktop?

Comment: virtual machine with windows installed

Comment: can you update the question with the jenkins.xml file?